# How can I Host Multiple Wcf Service library in same IIS virtual directory

Tags: wcf, iis, wcf-library

I have a lot of WCF Service Library and each libary has multiple service. I want to host that libaries at one virtual directory in IIS. How can I do that. After that I don't to use config file I read that information from db. I can do that custom service host factory but how can I host Multiple Wcf Service library in same IIS virtual directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `*.svc` for each of your multiple service libraries inside that IIS virtual directory..

Each `SVC` file corresponds to one service (implementation class), so each service needs its own `*.svc` file - but you can absolutely have multiple `*.svc` files in a single directory, no problem

Comment: This way is not good for me. I have 150 WCF Service Library and Each Service Library has 100 service. I want to that service without svc file and web config I configure them dynamically

Comment: @Sinan Oran: that's **the way** to do it, at least in .NET 3.5; if you're on .NET 4, you could also use the "file-less activation" model. See the [Developer's Introduction to WCF 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx) to do this without physical *.svc files.

Comment: I found my solution.                                  http://blog.micic.ch/net/dynamic-iis-hosted-wcf-service                      in that address you can see

Comment: @Sinan Oran: seems overly complicated to me - but if it works for you - all the better!